# How to add a query argument when clicking a link, and then retrieve it in Hook callback

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create an archive page that shows only posts of a custom type made by a specific user. Without overriding the the Author archive page of said user, nor the posts archive page. Basically I wanna leave the default wordpress archives intact.

so far I fugured I would do something like

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('type', get_post_type(), get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta("ID")));?>">
posted by <?php the_author() ?>
</a>
```

this basically generates a link that goes like

```
www.example.com/author/john/?type=custom_type
```

now I am trying to retrieve the query argument that I added in the pre_get_posts hook callback function that I use in my functions.php file like so:

```
add_action("pre_get_posts",function($query){
///code to retrieve parameters goes here
}
```

the problem is that the only parameter I am getting in the $query paramter is the author username. As for the post type (aka the string that comes after "?type="). That part of the url does not show up in the query vars. I tried inspecting every property of the $query parameter that is being passed to the callback but I cant find that post type. I can only find the author.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

OK I realized what I was doing wrong
You cannot use a made up key name when creating a key value pair in query vars. In other words if you want to assign a value to a queryvar, the key of the var has to be one of the wordpress query var predefined names. The full list can be found here https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars
When using a made up name like "type" in my case, you can not  retrieve that value using the get_query_var method because the key value pair is not added to the query vars in the first place. Instead you have to manually retrieve it from the super global variable $_GET[<variable_name>] so in my case I had to look in $_GET["type"]